# TypeError: export_users_xls() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views, django-excel

when I am trying to run i got this error

```
File "/home/normsoftware/WORK/JVB/healthtracker/quicklook/urls.py", line 39, in <module>
    url(r'^users/print$',views.export_users_xls(),name="Exceldata"),
TypeError: export_users_xls() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

**views.py**

```
def export_users_xls(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="users.xls"'

    wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
    ws = wb.add_sheet('Users')

    # Sheet header, first row
    row_num = 0

    font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
    font_style.font.bold = True

    columns = ['first', 'last',]

    for col_num in range(len(columns)):
        ws.write(row_num, col_num, columns[col_num], font_style)

    # Sheet body, remaining rows
    font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()

    rows = Registration.objects.all().values_list('first', 'last')
    for row in rows:
        row_num += 1
        for col_num in range(len(row)):
            ws.write(row_num, col_num, row[col_num], font_style)

    wb.save(response)
    return response
```

all line indentations are correct

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^users/print$',views.export_users_xls(),name="Exceldata"),
```

Comment: remove the parenthesis in `views.export_users_xls()` in `urls.py`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your url to this:
url(r'^users/print$',views.export_users_xls ,name="Exceldata")

as you see I am not executing export_users function (so remove your parenthesis), see this examples:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#example